# java.util.NoSuchElementException when run with Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have a Queue containing 10 elements, and I start 100 threads of which 6 may run concurrently, controlled by a Semaphore.  When each thread runs, it takes the head element then adds it to the tail.   But sometimes I get this exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)
 at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:685)
 at IBM.SemApp$1.run(SemApp.java:27)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;    
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class SemApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue queueB = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        queueB.add("Object " + i);
    }

    Runnable limitedCall = new Runnable() {
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(6);
        int count = 0;

        public void run() {
            int time = rand.nextInt(15);

            try {
                available.acquire();
                String A = (String) queueB.remove();
                queueB.add(A);
                available.release();
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        new Thread(limitedCall).start();
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that your increment of `count` is not atomic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `LinkedList` is not a thread-safe structure.

Therefore, it should not be shared and modified by multiple concurrent threads as the changes on `queueB` might not be properly "communicated" to other threads.

Try using a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) instead.

Also, use an `AtomicLong` for `count` for the same reason: it is shared in between several threads and you want to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that up to six threads may be operating on the queue concurrently means that modifications are not safe.